# Local blasting (16SrRNA) - taxonomy annotations from NCBI different from Silva

Tags: blast, ncbi

I am performing local blasting against both the NCBI database and the Silva database using this commands:

```
blastn -db db/16SMicrobial -query input.fa -out outputNCBI.csv -task blastn -dust no -max_target_seqs 1 -outfmt "10 pident evalue bitscore score seqid stitle staxids scomnames sscinames sskingdom"
blastn -db db/Silva -query input.fa -out outputSilva.csv -task blastn -dust no -max_target_seqs 1 -outfmt "10 pident evalue bitscore score seqid stitle staxids scomnames sscinames sskingdom"
```

The problem comes with the results. The annotated taxonomy is completely different. I have manually checked some of them by blasting them  online and it seems that Silva is giving the right resuls, meaning the local Silva results coincide with online NCBI results.

Both databases are in the same file. This is what's in it:

```
@:~/Desktop/db$ ls -a
16SMicrobial.nni  Silva_119.fasta  taxdb.btd
16SMicrobial.nog  Silva_123.fasta  taxdb.bti
16SMicrobial.nhr  16SMicrobial.nsd  Silva.nhr        tax_slv_ssu_123.txt
16SMicrobial.nin  16SMicrobial.nsi  Silva.nin
16SMicrobial.nnd  16SMicrobial.nsq  Silva.nsq
```

Does anyone have any idea what could be the cause?

I would appreciate any help.

Greets,
Irina